# Export Features to Geodatabase Created in same Python Script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase, feature-class, workspace

I am new to learning Python for GIS. I am currently trying to create a script which creates a new geodatabase, then using a list, iterates through the features of an existing geodatabase and exports these features to the new geodatabase I just created earlier in the script. I have ended up receiving the error "TEST_GDB (the new created geodatabase) does not exist or is not supported" multiple times. I researched my problem, and got the closest to a solution at this link [Using geodatabase feature dataset created in ArcPy script as output/input location later on in same script?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208018/using-geodatabase-feature-dataset-created-in-arcpy-script-as-output-input-locati) however I am still receiving the same error. It is worth noting that existing geodatabase from which I am exporting the data from is a default geodatabase for an ArcGIS Pro project.

```
import arcpy
# set initial environments
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\My_Name\Documents\GIS\ODU_Home\PYTHON_ODU\Python_Script_Tool_Test\Python_Script_Tool_Test.gdb"
arcpy.env.OverwriteOutput = True

# create a list for all feature classes within old or existing geodatabase
OldData = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print("Features Listed")

#Initialize variables to use in CreateFileGDB tool
out_folder_path = r"C:\Users\My_Name\Documents\GIS\ODU_Home\PYTHON_ODU"
out_name = "Test_GDB"

# create a new geodatabase & set as new workspace
GDB = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(out_folder_path, out_name,)
print("New .gdb created")
ws = str(str(GDB) + "\\")
arcpy.env.workspace = ws
print("New Workspace")


exportList = []
print("New list initialized")

#export feature classes from old gdb to new gdb
for Old in OldData:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(Old, r"C:\Users\My_Name\Documents\GIS\ODU_Home\PYTHON_ODU\Test_GDB")
    exportlist.append(Old + "_NEW")
print("Existing Feature Classes Exported")
```

Comment: A file geodatabase name ***must*** end in `.gdb`.  You're just giving a directory, not a geodatabase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the correct Geodatabase name in this line

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(Old, r"C:\Users\My_Name\Documents\GIS\ODU_Home\PYTHON_ODU\Test_GDB")
```

The Geodatabase will have a `.gdb` suffix on the end which you've left off.

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(Old, r"C:\Users\My_Name\Documents\GIS\ODU_Home\PYTHON_ODU\Test_GDB.gdb")
```

But since you've already got a variable for your new Geodatabase you could just specify that instead

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(Old, GDB)
```

---

As an aside, I don't think you need the following line:

```
ws = str(str(GDB) + "\\")
```

There is no need to add the trailing slash into the path for `arcgis.env.workspace` or any other arcpy tool.

```
GDB = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(out_folder_path, out_name,)
print("New .gdb created")
arcpy.env.workspace = GDB
print("New Workspace")
```

If you need to join a filename to a path use `os.path.join()` to do it automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks @midavalo, this actually helped fix my problem. I'm surprised I missed such an obvious error. Thank you!

Comment: @MANUELSOLANO I suspect that removing the `_GDB` from the geodatabase name would make it easier to spot